# Evergreen trees

Tags: trees

We live in Sask. just bought this place a year ago and the evergreen trees are not doing well.  They did go through a dry year so we watered and fertilized thinking that would help. Branches are sparse and growth is mostly on the tips. Really don’t want to replace.  Need help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you post photos of the trees? Some evergreens can be really drought sensitive, particularly in areas with limited soil depth, and your description of growth only at the tips is commensurate with drought stress.